# Parse.Cloud.job promise not working

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise, parse-cloud-code

What I am trying to do here are:

1. Remove all contents in a class first, because every day the events.json file will be updated. I have my first question here: is there a better way to remove all contents from a database class on Parse?
2. Then I will send a request to get the events.json and store "name" and "id" of the result into a 2D array.
3. Then I will send multiple requests to get json files of each "name" and "id" pairs.
4. Finally, I will store the event detail into database. (one event per row) But now my code will terminate before it downloaded the json files.

Code:

```
function newLst(results) {
  var event = Parse.Object.extend("event");
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
      url: 'https://api.example.com/events/'+ results[i].name +'/'+ results[i].id +'.json',
      success: function(newLst) {
        var newJson = JSON.parse(newLst.text);
        var newEvent = new event();
        newEvent.set("eventId",newJson.data.id);
        newEvent.set("eventName",newJson.data.title);
        newEvent.save(null, {
          success: function(newEvent) {
            alert('New object created with objectId: ' + newEvent.id);
          },
          error: function(newEvent, error) {
            alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.message);
          }
        });
      },
      error: function(newLst) {
      }
    });
  }
};

Parse.Cloud.job("getevent", function(request, status) {
  var event = Parse.Object.extend("event");
  var query = new Parse.Query(event);
  query.notEqualTo("objectId", "lol");
  query.limit(1000);
  query.find({
    success: function(results) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
        var myObject = results[i];
        myObject.destroy({
          success: function(myObject) {
          },
          error: function(myObject, error) {
          }
        });
      }
    },
    error: function(error) {
      alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
  });
  var params = { url: 'https://api.example.com/events.json'};
  Parse.Cloud.httpRequest(params).then(function(httpResponse) {
      var results = [];
      var jsonobj = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text);
      for (var i = 0; i < jsonobj.data.length; i++) {
        var tmp2D = {"name":"id"}
        tmp2D.name = [jsonobj.data[i].name];
        tmp2D.id = [jsonobj.data[i].id];
        results.push(tmp2D);
      }
      newLst(results);
  }).then(function() {
      status.success("run job");
  }, function(error) {
      status.error(error);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my original answer is correct as a standalone.  Rather than make it unreadable with the additional code, here it is made very specific to your edit.

The key is to *eliminate passed callback functions*.  Everything below uses promises.  Another key idea is *decompose* the activities into logical chunks.

A couple of caveats:  (1) There's a lot of code there, and the chances that either your code is mistaken or mine is are still high, but this should communicate the gist of a better design.  (2) We're doing enough work in these functions that we might bump into a parse-imposed timeout.  Start out by testing all this with small counts.

Start with your question about destroying all instances of class...

```
// return a promise to destroy all instances of the "event" class
function destroyEvents() {
    // is your event class really named with lowercase?  uppercase is conventional
    var query = new Parse.Query("event");
    query.notEqualTo("objectId", "lol");  // doing this because the OP code did it.  not sure why
    query.limit(1000);
    return query.find().then(function(results) {
        return Parse.Object.destroyAll(results);
    });
}
```

Next, get remote events and format them as simple JSON.  See the comment.  I'm pretty sure your idea of a "2D array" was ill-advised, but I may be misunderstanding your data...

```
// return a promise to fetch remote events and format them as an array of objects
//
// note - this differs from the OP data.  this will evaluate to:
// [ { "name":"someName0", id:"someId0" }, { "name":"someName1", id:"someId1" }, ...]
//
// original code was producing:
// [ { "name":["someName0"], id:["someId0"] }, { "name":["someName1"], id:["someId1"] }, ...]
// 
function fetchRemoteEvents() {
    var params = { url: 'https://api.example.com/events.json'};
    return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest(params).then(function(httpResponse) {
        var results = [];
        var remoteEvents = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text).data;
        for (var i = 0; i < remoteEvents.length; i++) {
            var remoteEvent = { "name": remoteEvents[i].name, "id": remoteEvents[i].id };
            results.push(remoteEvent);
        }
        return results;
    });
}
```

Please double check all of my work above regarding the format (e.g. response.text, JSON.parse().data, etc).

Its too easy to get confused when you mix callbacks and promises, and even worse when you're generating promises in a loop.  Here again, we break out a simple operation, to create a single parse.com object based on one of the single remote events we got in the function above...

```
// return a promise to create a new native event based on a remoteEvent
function nativeEventFromRemoteEvent(remoteEvent) {
    var url = 'https://api.example.com/events/'+ remoteEvent.name +'/'+ remoteEvent.id +'.json';
    return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({ url:url }).then(function(response) {
        var eventDetail = JSON.parse(response.text).data;
        var Event = Parse.Object.extend("event");
        var event = new Event();
        event.set("eventId", eventDetail.id);
        event.set("eventName", eventDetail.title);
        return event.save();
    });
}
```

Finally, we can bring it together in a job that is simple to read, certain to do things in the desired order, and certain to call success() when (and only when) it finishes successfully...

```
// the parse job removes all events, fetches remote data that describe events
// then builds events from those descriptions
Parse.Cloud.job("getevent", function(request, status) {
    destroyEvents().then(function() {
        return fetchRemoteEvents();
    }).then(function(remoteEvents) {
        var newEventPromises = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < remoteEvents.length; i++) {
            var remoteEvent = remoteEvents[i];
            newEventPromises.push(nativeEventFromRemoteEvent(remoteEvent));
        }
        return Parse.Promise.when(newEventPromises);
    }).then(function() {
        status.success("run job");
    }, function(error) {
        status.error(error);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The reason I wrote "query.notEqualTo("objectId", "lol");" is because I want to match all records and then delete them. Now I have removed it.

Answer (score 0):

The posted code does just one http request so there's no need for an array of promises or the invocation of `Promise.when()`.  The rest of what might be happening is obscured by mixing the callback parameters to httpRequest with the promises and the assignment inside the push.

Here's a clarified rewrite:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("getevent", function(request, status) {
    var promises = [];
    var params = { url: 'https://api.example.com'};
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest(params).then(function(httpResponse) {
        var results = [];
        var jsonobj = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text);
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonobj.data.length; i++) {
            // some code
        }
    }).then(function() {
        status.success("run job");
    }, function(error) {
        status.error(error);
    });
});
```

But there's a very strong caveat here: this works only if ("// some code") that appears in your original post doesn't itself try to do any asynch work, database or otherwise.

Lets say you do need to do asynch work in that loop.  Move that work to a promise-returning function collect those in an array, and *then* use Promise.when(). e.g....

```
// return a promise to look up some object, change it and save it...
function findChangeSave(someJSON) {
    var query = new Parse.Query("SomeClass");
    query.equalTo("someAttribute", someJSON.lookupAttribute);
    return query.first().then(function(object) {
        object.set("someOtherAttribute", someJSON.otherAttribute);
        return object.save();
    });
}
```

Then, in your loop...

```
        var jsonobj = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text);
        var promises = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonobj.data.length; i++) {
            // some code, which is really:
            var someJSON = jsonobj.data[i];
            promises.push(findChangeSave(someJSON));
        }
        return Parse.Promise.when(promises);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Actually I also have query.find() before the "var promises = [];" statement. Does this affects the solution? Should I something like "query.find().then(Parse.Cloud.httpRequest(params).then(..."?

Comment: Yes.  That would affect the solution.  I can probably help if you add your complete code in an edit.

Comment: @meteor - Rather than further clutter this answer (which is correct as a standalone, imo), I added a new answer below that is specifically responsive to the requirements and code in your edit.